# Returning a jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I want, in a certain case, not to query the server with an ajax request but to return an empty array right away.
The return type of the function must be a Deferred. (caller is able to chain `.then` to invocations).
I came up with the following:

```
if(noNeedForAjax) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.resolve([]);
    return d;
}

return $.when( ...
```

However, it is surprising you cannot do it in one line. I was expecting that `$.Deferred().resolve([])` would do the same, but apparently it does not.

Why does not `.resolve()` return `this`?

Is it possible to achieve the same in one return statement?

Comment: Looks like that works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pH23q/

Comment: The documentation says that `resolve` returns a Deferred, so I'd expect the one line version to work as it does in Jason P's jsFiddle. Not sure why you're encountering problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy pointed out, try without `return`

```
if(noNeedForAjax) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    d.resolve([]);
    d;
};
```

or, for "do it in one line"

```
if (noNeedForAjax) {$.when(function() {return []})};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What is `d;` supposed to do?

Comment: @Jason P `resolved` `deferred`. It may help to post what the "chained" `then` deferred requirement is, or may be. Thanks.

Comment: I know `d` is a resolved deferred, but the expression `d;` doesn't actually _do_ anything.

Comment: @Jason P What is the requirement? Or, what is required _next_, after `resolved` empty array? What is next step in/of requirement with prospective `then`, et al? The original question mentioned returning an empty array, without specifying what was to be "done" with it; at least cannot seem to garner more from original question. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: BTW - you can even do it shorter. You're idea has two $.when, so I simply turned the whole thing into a `?:` statement: `$.when( noNeedForAjax ? [] : $.ajax(...) ).then(...)` - it turns out when() can accept an object and use it as a return value. That's just awesome.

Comment: @Jacob Interesting approach. This `noNeedForAjax ? [] : $.ajax(...)` doe not have to be in/as `function` (form)? Will this `$.when( (1 === 1 ? console.log(new Date().getTime()) : console.log(window)) )` work?

Comment: here's some of $.when source: `deferred = length <= 1 && firstParam && jQuery.isFunction( firstParam.promise ) ? firstParam : jQuery.Deferred(),` - so I guess both will work